# Infinite loop with java code, Scanner object buffer may be

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, infinite-loop

I'm trying to read a number for a switch case option but I'm stuck with an exception. I will try to explain the problem better in code:

```
do{
    try{
        loop=false;
        int op=teclado.nextInt();
        //I tryed a teclado.nextLine() here cause i saw in other Q but didn't work
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException ex){
        System.out.println("Invalid character. Try again.");
        loop=true;//At the catch bolck i change the loop value
    }
}while(loop);//When loop is true it instantly go to the catch part over and over again and never ask for an int again
```

When I type an int it works perfectly, but the exception makes it start over. The second time, the program does not ask for the int (I think it could be a buffer and I need something like `fflush(stdin)` in C), and the buffer just starts writing like crazy.

Comment: What's the format of the file you're reading in?  It could be that it's stumbling on something that isn't an integer (which is why `InputMismatchException` would be raised.

Comment: I'm reading from keyboard "Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);"

Comment: Did you use the same scanner before entering the do-while loop?

Comment: Nope, I start the method, declare the scanner then the code above and close method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You would be well-served creating a new instance of `Scanner` from within the `catch` to get the input should you fail.</s>  **EDIT:**  You can use a `Scanner.nextLine()` to advance past the newline character when you fail. A `do...while` loop may be inappropriate for this, since it guarantees that it will execute at least once.

A construct that may help you out more is a simple `while` loop.  This is actually a `while-true-break` type of loop, which breaks on valid input.

```
while(true) {
    try {
        op=teclado.nextInt();
        break;
    } catch(InputMismatchException ex){
        System.out.println("Invalid character. Try again.");
        teclado.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `op == new Integer(op)`? `op` is already declared as `int`, just use `break` without any validation.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that too.  Seems pretty pointless.  Thanks for that, @Eng.Fouad!

Comment: One more thing, there is no need to create new Scanner every time, just use `teclado.nextLine();`. Basically, the problem is because there is a `\n` character in the buffer from the user (After pressing Enter), and to solve the problem, you can discard the new-line character with `teclado.nextLine();`. Anyway, you deserve +1 :)

Comment: Thank you really much it works great but there is still something i can't understand, i tryed the teclado.nextline(); down the op=teclado.nextInt(); and it didn't work

Comment: @MarkE `teclado.nextLine();` should be invoked inside a `finally` block, to guarantee that it will be invoked in both cases; the user enters a valid integer, and the user enters an invalid integer and an exception is thrown.